# Why can't I return when catching an exception with try:?

Tags: python

I would like to return from a function upon some conditions when catching an exception:

```
def myfunc():
    try:
        a = 1
    except:
        pass
    else:
        if a == 1:
            return a
    finally:
        return 100

x = myfunc()
print(x)
```

My expectation for the code above was that

- `try` succeeds (no exception raised)
- goes to `else` where the condition is met
- returns `a` from function, the rest of the code is not ran

As you can imagine, I get as a result `100`, which means that the `finally` clause was assessed.

Since I am obviously missing something I ran this though a debugger and I indeed reach the `return a` line but do not actually return at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`finally` is **always** executed. You are returning just fine, it is just that you misunderstood what the `finally` suite *does*.

From the [`try` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When a `return`, `break` or `continue` statement is executed in the `try` suite of a `try...finally` statement, the `finally` clause is also executed ‘on the way out.’

In this context, the `except` and `else` handlers are part of the `try` suite still.

The `finally` suite is meant as a clean-up handler; once you enter the `try` suite, `finally` is guaranteed to be executed, no matter what happens. This can also mean you can alter what is returned. This is explicitly documented:

> The return value of a function is determined by the last `return`
>   statement executed. Since the `finally` clause always executes, a `return`
>   statement executed in the `finally` clause will always be the last one
>   executed:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> def foo():
> ...     try:
> ...         return 'try'
> ...     finally:
> ...         return 'finally'
> ...
> >>> foo()
> 'finally'
> ```

Comment: I understand that `finally` is always executed as part of the `try` flow, but I thought `return` means "leave the function right now and send back whatever"? Apparently the `try`suite has higher priority, so to speak.

Comment: @WoJ: the `finally` is still *always* executed. The moment you enter a `try` statement, **any** way out of that block will include executing the `finally` suite. That's the whole reason for that part of the statement, to provide clean-up code *no matter what happens*.

Answer (score 1):

The finally statement is always executed in as per the try statement documentation. For your function you may wish to use an "else if"

```
def myfunc():
 try:
    a = 1
except:
    pass
elif: a == 1:
        return a
else:
        return 100

x = myfunc()
print(x)
```